# How can I smooth out this on mouseover animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover, continuous

I have a div that it animating left and right based on the mouse's position, but it's too jittery (especially in IE).

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with a `.stop()` being inside the mousemove function, thus being called hundreds of times in seconds, but it's the best I can get it.  I want it to be a clean, continuous animation...

#### jQuery

```
$('#videoThumbContainer').mousemove(function(e){

    var offset = $(this).offset(),
    containerWidth = $(this).width(),
    runnerWidth = $('#videoThumbRunner').width(),
    relativeX = e.pageX - offset.left,
    difference = parseInt(containerWidth - runnerWidth),
    position = (relativeX / containerWidth) * difference;

    if (runnerWidth > containerWidth) {

        $('#videoThumbRunner').stop().animate({left: position}, 50, 'linear');
    }
});
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/cbXh5/

Comment: The stop definitely is causing the jitteryness, you can use .stop(true) to help it a little bit but not much.  Have you considered something other than mousemove, that fires so many times that you are going to potentially cripple slow machines and old browsers.

Comment: One possible improvement could be to use a cache - `var $runner = $('#videoThumbRunner');`.

Comment: @Richard I can't believe I didn't realize that.  However, it doesn't work with a new direction I'm taking, with safe zones on the left and right. http://jsfiddle.net/cbXh5/2/ Kudos though